# How to Prevent Hyphenation for Minipages but Allow It Everywhere Else

Tags: minipage, hyphenation, hyphenat

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % To prevent hyphenation within entire document.

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\begin{minipage}{5in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{{\color{red}{Einstein on Simplicity:}} ``Out of Complexity, Find Simplicity.'' ``Everything Should be Made as Simple as Possible, but Not Simpler.'' ``If You Can't Explain It Simply, You Don't Understand It Well Enough.''}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

I would like, in general, to prevent hyphenation within such minipages.

I know that if I use `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` in the preamble, I will prevent hyphenation throughout the document---which I don't want to do.

In the case of the MWE, inserting `\linebreak` immediately after "made as" ought to work; however, it may often occur that such a "fix" will impose a hyphenation somewhere earlier in the minipage.

QUESTION: How may hyphenation be prevented only for minipages, but allowed everywhere else in the document?

Thank you.

Comment: `\sloppy` (opposite of `\fussy`) usually does the trick.

Comment: @John Kormylo I've used `\sloppy` once or twice before, globally. I guess it can be used locally, I didn't think of it. I read somewhere an objection to its use but I don't recall exactly what it was, other than it may deliver what the name implies. When I used it, it wasn't that bad that I recall. What is `\fussy`?

Comment: \fussy is the default, in case you want to turn \sloppy off.  OTOH, inside a minipage the change is local to the minipage.

Comment: Many thanks. @John Kormylo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short paragraphs I use

```
    \tolerance=1
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \hbadness=10000
```

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % To prevent hyphenation within entire document.

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \Large
    \begin{minipage}{5in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
        \tolerance=1
        \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
        \hyphenpenalty=10000
        \hbadness=10000
        \textbf{{\color{red}{Einstein on Simplicity:}} ``Out of Complexity, Find Simplicity.'' ``Everything Should be Made as Simple as Possible, but Not Simpler.'' ``If You Can't Explain It Simply, You Don't Understand It Well Enough.''}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to make an environment for this type of object.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % for wider text
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{myquote}[2][5in]
 {%
  \begin{minipage}{#1}
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\fill}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{-\leftskip}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{\stretch{2}}%
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{\textwidth}% avoid overfull boxes if really possible
  \pretolerance=0 % don't try the useless first pass
  \hyphenpenalty=10000 % no hyphenation
  \hbadness=10000 % don't report bad boxes
  \frenchspacing % end of sentence space might become really wide
  \bfseries
  \textcolor{red}{#2:} \ignorespaces
 }
 {\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myquote}{Einstein on Simplicity}
``Out of Complexity, Find Simplicity.'' 
``Everything Should be Made as Simple as Possible, but Not Simpler.'' 
``If You Can't Explain It Simply, You Don't Understand It Well Enough.''
\end{myquote}

\bigskip

\begin{myquote}[4.5in]{Einstein on Simplicity}
``Out of Complexity, Find Simplicity.'' 
``Everything Should be Made as Simple as Possible, but Not Simpler.'' 
``If You Can't Explain It Simply, You Don't Understand It Well Enough.''
\end{myquote}

\bigskip

\begin{myquote}[4in]{Einstein on Simplicity}
``Out of Complexity, Find Simplicity.'' 
``Everything Should be Made as Simple as Possible, but Not Simpler.'' 
``If You Can't Explain It Simply, You Don't Understand It Well Enough.''
\end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I remove `\frenchspacing`, I get

[image]

I find this really bad anyway.